# SQLAlchemy : is there any good automated way to rename columns

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, alias

I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM for a few days and i'm looking for a way to get tablename prefix in the results of `Session.query()`.

For instance  :

```
myId = 4
...
data = session.query(Email.address).filter(Email.id==str(myId)).one()

print data.keys()
```

This would display :

```
("address",)
```

And i would like to get something like :

```
("Email.address",)
```

Is there any way to do it, without changing the class attributes and the table column names.
This example is a bit dummy but in a more general purpose i would like to prefix all column names by table names in result to make sure the results are always under the same format, even if there are **joins** in queries.
I've read things about `aliased()`, many posts here but nothing satisfied me.
Can someone please enlighten me on this ?

Thank you.

---

EDIT:

Thanks a lot for your answer @alecxe. I finally manage to do what i wanted. Here is the first batch of my code, there is probably many things to improve :

```
query = self.session.query(Email.address,User.name)
cols = [{str(column['name']):str(column['expr'])} for column in query.column_descriptions]
someone = query.filter(User.name==str(curName)).all()

r = []
for res in someone :
    p = {}
    for c in map(str,res.__dict__):
        if not c.startswith('_'):
            for k in cols:
                if c == k.keys()[0]:
                    p[k[c]] = res.__dict__[c]
    r.append(p)
print r
```

The output is :

```
[{'Email.address': u'john@foobaz.com', 'User.name': u'John'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to [column_descriptions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.column_descriptions):

```
query = session.query(Email.address)
print [str(column['expr']) for column in query.column_descriptions]  # should print ["Email.address"]

data = query.filter(Email.id==str(myId)).one()
```

Hope that helps.